# EmbeddedKafka and GraalVM in Springboot tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, graalvm-native-image, embedded-kafka

I want to use EmbeddedKafka with GraalVM using Spring boot in tests. When I run the test it goes to idle and Waiting until the timeout happens. Is there any idea how to use them together?

When I run the test it goes to idle and Waiting until the timeout happens.

Comment: Not sure about any connection between Kafka and GraalVM. Question is how is your setup? Are you using a kafka on your local machine? and what port you are giving when using Embedded Kafka? Because the way I see it, it should not be same when both embedded and actual kafka cluster is on same machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.